# How to merge objects with empty string values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am struggling to merge 2 objects. Both of them have nested objects and the value of the arbitrary key can be an empty string.

```
const obj1 = { name: "Arthur", lastName: "King", address: {
  street: "",
  city: "Some city",
  zip: "26772",
}};

const obj2 = { name: "", lastName: "", address: {
  street: "Some street",
  city: "",
  zip: "",
}};
```

`Object.assign` and spread operator are not working as they are doing shallow merge which is not my case, even if I separately merge the nested objects.

The problem is that merging 2 objects which have empty string values doesn't work as expected as Javascript treats empty strings as a value not like `undefined` or `null`.

```
const merged = {...obj1, ...obj2, address: {...obj1.address, ...obj2.address}}

The result will be

{
    "name": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "address": {
        "street": "Some street",
        "city": "",
        "zip": ""
    }
}
```

The desired result could be the below one, but somehow it doesn't ignore empty values and treats them like a value.

```
{
    "name": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "address": {
        "street": "Some street",
        "city": "Some city",
        "zip": "26772"
    }
}
```

One of the workarounds could be removing all the empty string values from the objects and then do merge but IMHO it's a total overkill.

Comment: What if both values of some property are not the empty string?

Comment: Can you explain more about the merging requirements you're trying to achieve? what would be each value in the target object depending on those in obj1 and obj2?

Comment: So, in the desired result only the `"nested object"` named `"address"` must be populated (ie, merged using `obj1` & `obj2` values) and other props (`name`, `lastName`, and any others if present) need to be set to empty-string, correct?

Comment: @jsN00b Let's just ignore top-level values, I only need nested objects to be merged correctly.

Comment: @MikeM Then the source branch should have higher priority.And if the target branch's nested object value is filled string and the source's nested object value is empty, it should keep the filled one, like it should treat as `EMPTY STRING === undefined`

Comment: @MajedBadawi It should behave the same way as it's behaving with undefined values.

Comment: do you have the same object structure for both objects?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, totally the same. The first one is the default object.

Comment: `""` IS a value as far as the language is concerned.  So, if you want to treat it like its not a value, then you will have to write custom code to do the merge that checks for the values that you want to treat as a non-value.

Answer (score 4):

You could greate a new object by taking the entries and check if a value is an object, then take the merged nested objects as value.

This approach works only for same object structures.

```js
const
    merge = (a, b) => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(a)
        .map(([k, v]) =>  [k, v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? merge(v, b[k])
            : v || b[k]
        ])
    ),
    obj1 = { name: "Arthur", lastName: "King", address: { street: "", city: "Some city", zip: "26772" } },
    obj2 = { name: "", lastName: "", address: { street: "Some street", city: "", zip: "" } },
    merged = merge(obj1, obj2);

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Assumes `a` will not have properties with falsey values such as `0` or `false`. Of course, the assumption will be correct if the values are all strings.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const obj1 = { name: "Arthur", lastName: "King", address: {
  street: "",
  city: "Some city",
  zip: "26772",
}};

const obj2 = { name: "", lastName: "", address: {
  street: "Some street",
  city: "",
  zip: "",
}};

// ===

function mergeObject (a, b) {
  const merged = {};
  
  Object.entries(a).forEach(([key, aValue]) => {
    const bValue = b[key];
    let mergedValue = null;
    
    if (typeof aValue === 'object') {
      mergedValue = mergeObject(aValue, bValue);
    }
    
    if (typeof aValue !== 'object') {
      const isAValueEmpty = aValue === '' || aValue === undefined || aValue === null;
      
      mergedValue = isAValueEmpty ? bValue : aValue;
    }
    
    merged[key] = mergedValue;
  });
  
  return merged;
}

console.log(mergeObject(obj1, obj2));
```

The idea here is that you have a particular type of "is empty" that doesn't match the default. So, we make a custom function to use that condition and then use recursive calls to that function as-needed.

Objects don't have the easiest way to iterate on them with `myObject.map()` like arrays, but since you know the structure you expect we can assume that `Object.entries(myObject)` will get what you expect.

...

Alternative based on some of the discussion although not sure how readable this is.

The key point is the way the empty status is determined. The use of switch / if / else / ternary I think is up to preference.

```js
const obj1 = { name: "Arthur", lastName: "King", address: {
  street: "",
  city: "Some city",
  zip: "26772",
}};

const obj2 = { name: "", lastName: "", address: {
  street: "Some street",
  city: "",
  zip: "",
}};

// ===



function mergeObject (a, b) {
  function isValueEmpty(value) {
    return value === ''
      || value === undefined
      || value === null;
  }
  
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).map(([key, aValue]) => {
    const bValue = b[key];      

    return [
      key,
      typeof aValue === 'object'
        ? mergeObject(aValue, bValue)
        : (isValueEmpty(aValue)
            ? bValue
            : aValue
          )
    ];
  }));
}

console.log(mergeObject(obj1, obj2));
```

Comment: I find it easier to reason with simple if statements rather than chained if / else / etc. It's a readability preference and I think in this situation, it's OK to use either. I do like the other answer with `Object.fromEntries()` and the map and I would suggest that over this. :)

Comment: Ah, I had not thought of that and while probably uncommon, I could see how that might happen. Maybe a switch statement would be clearer? I feel like people can have strong opinions about ternaries, switches, ifs, etc. :) I'm not sure of stack overflow best practices, so I'm not sure how much I should edit this answer. I hope the main point is helpful and some of the other choices like the if / else someone can decide their own path. As mentioned in the previous comment, I would use `Object.fromEntries()` which changes a lot of the structure of this code. Another answer already shows that.

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively merge the items. Note that the snippet below has no support for arrays yet, because you had no arrays. If you want to support arrays as well, let me know.

```js
function merge(main, secondary, deeper) {
    let primary = deeper ? structuredClone(main) : main;
    for (let sKey in secondary) {
        if (!primary[sKey]) primary[sKey] = secondary[sKey];
        else {
            if (typeof secondary === "object") {
                merge(primary[sKey], secondary[sKey], deeper);
            } else {
                if ([undefined, null, ""].indexOf(primary[sKey]) >= 0) primary[sKey] = secondary[sKey];
            }
        }
    }
    return primary;
}

const obj1 = { name: "Arthur", lastName: "King", address: {
  street: "",
  city: "Some city",
  zip: "26772",
}};

const obj2 = { name: "", lastName: "", address: {
  street: "Some street",
  city: "",
  zip: "",
}};

console.log(merge(obj1, obj2));
```

Comment: Modifies the source object rather than returning a new object.

Comment: @MikeM thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer to create a new object inside the method.

Comment: The use of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is controversial in this context and may attract scorn.

Comment: @MikeM what do you propose instead?

Comment: @LajosArpad  _what do you propose instead?_ --> Not sure about what MikeM may propose; however, if your objective is to deep-copy: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

Comment: @jsN00b thanks for the instructive comment. Edited my answer accordingly.